# authentication for server side

Tags: javascript, jwt

authentication jsonwebtoken midleware
sometime this message appaer while i alrd instal jwt
JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
at module.exports [as verify] (/Users/wedawiguna/Documents/Hacktive/bacth66/phase2/repeticiLC3/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:60:17)

````js
const { User } = require("../models");
const { verifyToken } = require("../helpers/jwt");
async function authentication(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    if (!authorization) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }

    const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];

    const decoded = verifyToken(token);

    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: error.message });
    } // pindah kan ke error handler
    next(error);
  }
}

module.exports = authentication;


template for authentication
```js
````